# Can't set bulk_create to a variable (Django)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm using bulk_create to create multiple profiles:

```
def bulk_create_and_get(cls, profile_ids):
    tickets_to_create = []
    for profile_id in profile_ids:
        ticket = cls(profile_id=profile_id)
        tickets_to_create.append(ticket)

    cls.objects.bulk_create(tickets_to_create)
```

Were the `cls` is the `Ticket` Class model

Can I save my bulk_create to a variable and return it?

```
created_tickets = cls.objects.bulk_create(tickets_to_create)
```

Instead of querying for the tickets I just created?

```
created_tickets = cls.objects.filter(
            Q(profile_id__in=profile_ids) |
            Q(unregistered_profile_id__in=profile_ids)
          )

return created_tickets
```

Comment: yes, you can do it. bulk_create creates the tickets and return them.

Comment: Just tried, it returned a list of the ids, I initially used. Maybe, It's because i'm using an old version of Django

Comment: what is your Django version?

Comment: The version I'm running is django 1.9.11